# create list of increasing number of repeated characters

Tags: python, regex, escaping, repeat

I'm trying to create this kind of output in Python

```
["k", "kk", "kkk", "kkkk", ...]
["rep", "reprep", "repreprep", ...]
```

That is a list of n elements, made of the same character (or small group of characters) repeated X times, X being increased by one for each element.

I can't find a way to do this easily, without loops..
Thanks,

Comment: `[k * i for i in range(1, n)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
repeating_value = "k" #Assign the value which do you want to be repeated
total_times=5 #how many times do you want
expected_list=[repeating_value*i for i in range(1,total_times+1)]
print(expected_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a generator using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), remember the property of "multiplying" strings in python by a number, where they will be replicated and concatenated `nth` times, where for example `"a"*3 == "aaa"` :

```
import itertools
def genSeq(item):
    yield from (item*i for i in itertools.count())
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/BisqueNaturalBinarytree)

Comment: thanks lot for this great tool and the example! that's almost over quality, because i'm not very familiar with iterators, i just needed a list :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following is by far the easiest which I have built upon the comment by the user3483203 which eliminates initial empty value.

```
var = 'rep'
list = [var * i for i in range(1,x,1)]
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
character = 'k'
_range = 5

output = [k*x for k in character for x in range(1, _range + 1)]
print(output)
```

I would multiple my character by a specified number in the range, and then I would simply iterate through the range in a list comprehension. We add 1 to the end of the range in order to get the full range.

Here is your output:

```
['k', 'kk', 'kkk', 'kkkk', 'kkkkk']
```